# If $AB = 0$, prove that the columns of matrix $B$ are vectors in the kernel of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices.
>
> If $AB=0$, prove that the columns of matrix $B$ are vectors in the kernel of $Ax=0$.

I'm not sure how to approach this. I know that if $B = 0$ and $A$ isn't, then $Ax=0$ is when $x=0=B$. But what if $A=0$? Seems like in this case B doesn't have to be a part of the kernel.

Or perhaps I'm just missing something?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the different matrix products. Your result almost immediately follows regarding to the use of a formula for the matrix multiplication.

Comment: If A is the zero matrix then everything is in the kernel, hence all columns of B by default are in the kernel.

Comment: @Anurga 
Doesn't it means that everything is just possible in the kernel?
I mean, it is possible that B will not be in the kernel, since you can have any kind of solution that is different from B.

Comment: Sorry if I got it wrong, I'm translating the term from my native language which is not English. I was referring to the solution-space, or in other words all the possible solutions for the equation Ax=0.

Comment: I see, thanks for clearing it up!
Just to make sure I understand the way to prove this-
If A=0 then everything is possible in the kernel, which means B is also possible, and therefore B is in the kernel.
If B=0 and A is not zero, can I say that the kernel is only zero, which equals to B (both are zeros...)?

Comment: If A is not zero and B is zero, then all the column vectors of B are zero too. Since 0 is part of the kernel for every matrix, the column vectors are part of the kernel of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$ AB = \begin{pmatrix} Ab^1 && ... && Ab^n \end{pmatrix} $$

Where $b^i$ is the i-th column vector and the right side is the matrix you get by the multiplication.

**Details:**
By comparing the two matrices you can now conclude that for all the column vectors $b$ of B it holds that:

$$ Ab = 0 $$

So all column vectors of B are in the kernel of A.

Answer (score 0):

It results from the very definition of matrix multiplication: to obtain column $j$ in the product $AB$, you multiply each line of $A$ with column $j$ of $B$, i.e. you multiply $A$ by column $j$ of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

The columns of $B$ are exactly the vectors $B e_i$ where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors.  Then since $AB = 0$, $AB e_i = 0$, so $A(B e_i) = 0$, so $B e_i \in \ker A$.